# Is there any word for the person who is running the business of "Prostitution"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word for the person who is running the business of "Prostitution" ?

Who indulge or force, girls or woman in the business of prostitution?

Comment: Did you try looking it up in Wikipedia?

Comment: yes,but found nothing.

Comment: The correct answer given by Łukasz below is also given in the Wikipedia article in its terminology section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes :)

Quick research from Polish word (sutener) to referring English [article in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procuring_%28prostitution%29), and I've found the following:

Such person is called a **procurer** (and what he's doing, is called **procuring**).

Colloquially they are called **pimp** (male) and **madam** (female).

Comment: It's possible that the OP is looking for “human trafficker,” which is also discussed in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

A woman in charge of a brothel is sometimes called a *madam*.

Comment: But madam is very general word which can be used for any woman responsible for some duty. I am looking for something highly specific.

Comment: _Pimp_ is the other main word for this sort of thing, possibly closer to what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @dev _Madam_ is highly specific, it just has more than one meaning. But usually this is exactly what it means unless used as a title.

Comment: Context is everything.

Comment: The OED's fifth definition of _madam_ is 'a female brothel-keeper'. It has been so used since the late nineteenth century.